# Fail in loading flash loader on IAR Workbench

Tags: embedded, stm32, iar, flash-memory

I am working on IAR Workbench platform V7.70.1 and I am triying to download a simple code (a simple main with a while(1) only into it), but I'm not succeding to download the code on the processor. I am using the board NUCLEO-F401RE of STM company, based on the processor STM32F401RE. I'm am getting the following message:

> `Failed to load flash loader: C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.5\arm\config\flashloader\ST\FlashSTM32F401xE.flash`

If someone is familiar with the issue, some help would save me. I read something about this issue on [this link](http://forum.segger.com/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=178) but I did not understand what I'm supposed to do:

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try the solution suggested in the link (change the reset type in the debugger setup)?  The error message you are seing could have multiple causes, so it is not necessarily the case that that is your problem, but until you have tested that it is hard to help.

Comment: I would like to do so but I don't know how. I didn't understand what they meant and what I should do. Do you know how ?

Comment: I tried to completely erase the flash memory on the device but this operation also requires to download the flash loader so I don't know what to do...

Comment: A common issue is that hardware configuration not correct (lower power, open GND, open wires) . Please use a voltmeter to check the power supply on your board. Recheck your board specification parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot nitro2, it was actually the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

the solution is very simple - 
go to Project->Option->Debugger->Download  - uncheck the checkbox "Override default.board file".

have a good day
Itshak

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ST-Link reset type. Often the ST debug interface can not connect due to the processor state.

Form the menu bar select **Project->Options** then **ST-Link** from the list on the left. The Reset box is normally set to **Normal** but can be changed to **Connect during reset** which will hold the processor in reset while connecting the debugger before any code can execute.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

I erase my Port with "CrossCore Serial Flash Programmer"
Then under Project->Options->Debugger->CMSIS DAP->Setup I choose "Software".
Then I debug once.
Then I choose "Hardware" in the same setting window.
Debug again.
Then it worked. Some other software might mess up the correct serial settings, thats why you have to erase and reset them.